# Alguem sabe dizer porque não está carregando essa imagem (css)?

Tags: javascript, css

Estou fazendo um exercicio aqui, mas não estou conseguindo carregar a imagem `img/baladinha.jpg`. Obs: ainda não coloquei imagens no body

#### Codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">     
<head> 
    <title> JavaScript CinemaBaladinha</title>  
    <style>
        div {
            margin:0 auto; width:940px; text-align:center;
        }

        #topo {
            background:url(img/baladinha.jpg) no-repeat;   
        }
    </style>

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/CinemaBaladinha.js"> </script> 
</head>    
    <body>    
        <div id = "topo"/> 
        <div>
            <img />
            <img />
            <img />
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `div` não é um elemento que possa ser fechado em si mesmo. Portanto,

```
<div id = "topo"/>
```

está errado.

O correto é

```
<div id="topo"></div>
```

Além do mais, a `div` não possui altura definida. Por padrão, um elemento de bloco (que é o caso desse) possui 100% de `width` e `height: auto`, o que está deixando sua `div#topo` com altura igual a zero.

O que resolveria:

```
#topo{
    background: (img/baladinha.jpg);
    height: 200px;
}
```